# Problem in recording

Tags: java, audio-recording

I have a program that first plays: "please say your name".  It then records the name.

Part of my code is:

```
try {
    AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("sth.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audio);
    clip.start();
}
catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
    System.out.println(uae);
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(ioe);
}
catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
    System.out.println(lua);
}

r.captureAudio();
```

Here `r` is an instance of the main class.

The problem is that the recording goes like this:
It first plays "please enter your name" and then plays what I record with mic.

---

I am a beginner and don't have much experience with Java.

What changes should I make so that the recording contains only the microphone input and not "please enter your name"?

Comment: "pls give direct help" Please 1) Ask a question. 2) Use your shift key when typing messages. 3) Avoid immature nonsense words like 'pls' & 'ur'.

Comment: sorry I am new to stack overflow.. I will definitely take care in future

Comment: can anyone tell the amends i should make so that the recording contains only the microphone input and not "please enter your name"

Comment: I do not find your code snippet to be very clear.  1) There is no mention of functionality to get the user's name. 2) Playing a (prerecorded) `Clip` seems entirely unrelated to the problem, and 3) I don't know what the mysterious `r` object is.  BTW - a better thing to do with exceptions is to call `Exception.prtintStackTrace()`.  Not only is it more informative than `System.out.println(Exception)`, it is also less typing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your question.

Popping a `JOptionPane` (or modal `JDialog`) will block the GUI until dismissed.

If you pop one to say 'start recording', start the recording directly after that is closed and pop a new one with 'stop recording', the second will stop the rest of the program statements (but not the recording itself, as long as it is done in a `Thread`).

Comment: Here is the problem: the out put file plays" Please Enter Your Name Karan Dwivedi" ; instead it should play " Karan Dwivedi"

Comment: @Karan: I do not find your description very helpful at explaining.  Why not try to explain in an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) instead?  For the `sth.wav` instead hot-link to [leftright.wav](http://pscode.org/media/#sound) - [http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav](http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav) (and maybe loop it a few times).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `clip.drain()`, this will block current thread until the clip has finished playing. After that you can start capturing.

Comment: it seems to be the solution.. please elaborate as i am a beginner

Comment: @Karan Dwivedi: if this really solves your problem, make sure to accept the answer.